# Android : Call function when user close app from any activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

I want to call one function when the user closes the app from any activity. For e.g. the user opens the app and uses it for some time and then clicks on the home button and closes the app at that time I want to call one method.

How can I archive this.?

Currently I used onDestroy method for the call function but seems like it does work for me

Comment: Call method in onStop() as app is still running in the background and activity is not destroyed. For multiple activities you can make a base class for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state if you were doing this with JAVA or Kotlin, but not a big deal.
try onPause() This is called when the user presses the home button and the activity is no longer in the foreground.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        something();
    }
```

Comment: It’s also called when a dialog box appears on the screen or the user pulls down the notification bar, so it might not be suitable for the OP's use case.